# UITableView did present 30% of cell - iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

Is there a way to know when ~30% of the `UITableViewCell` was presented

This is too early:

[tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614883-tableview?changes=_3&language=objc) - Tells the delegate the table view **is about to draw** a cell for a particular row.

This is too late:

[tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:forRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614870-tableview?language=objc) - Tells the delegate that the specified cell **was removed** from the table.

Comment: but... but... why?

Comment: what holex said but you can use scrollViewDidScroll, check the tableviews visibleCells and then convert its frame as frame.intersection(view) then check if its more than 30% of cell bounds

Comment: 30% of all cells, or rendering of one cell?

Comment: Sounds like an intensive task for the simple delegation methods of UITableView of UIKit. You should think of another way to achieve what you are doing, maybe with SpriteKit or OpenGL (!). You should give more details of your implementation at least. Good luck

Comment: @holex, our data guy needs this info

Comment: I like the viewers ask "why would you do that?" and then they remember about the "tracking guy" and they are like "oh...that's why"

Comment: please check this in cellforRowAtIndexPath: tableview Delegate. when new cell is created then it will be called. 30% of cell = no of total rows / 0.3